# Right to install printer driver from printer server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer

Previously, I have posted on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606035/printersettings-isvalid-ever-false-and-driver-on-server), because I was believe that code is wrong. My goal is to check printer and tray on printer server and display this on a web page.

When I run pool with admin account, there is no problem. But if I run this with the AD account that is only a simple user, it is not working because it can't copy driver to "C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers\x64\3". I have granted the pool's user as total control on this directory, but no effect.

So, my question is, what is the good right to give to this user to copy the driver from printer server (grant this user as admin is not possible) ?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Look into the GPO settings for both computer and user config here: `Policies/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Printers/Point and Print Restrictions`

Comment: It is already done for computer. Is there the same action for user ?

Comment: Yes there is.  Because if you aren't deploying the printers to the computers then they'll need these settings for the user too.

Comment: Thank you, I have forwarded your answer to my GPO admin for action. Please post as answer that I can validate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the GPO settings for both computer and user config here: Policies/Administrative Templates/Control Panel/Printers/Point and Print Restrictions

Specifically for the user policy if you are wanting the user to be able to add the printer and download the driver from the server without a UAC prompt or elevated prompt.

Comment: The Point and Print Restrictions applies XP to 2008 only. For 2008r2 I think you'll need "Computer>Windows Settings>Security Settings>Security options>Devices: Prevent users from installing printer drivers when connecting to shared printers"

Answer (score -1):

add or create GPO for just computer

> Scope - Location - yourdomain.local 
>   Scope - Security Filtering - Authenticated users 
>   Details - GPO Status - User configuration settings disabled 
>   Settings
>
> > - Computer Configuration
> >
> >   > - Policies
> >   >
> >   >   > - Windows Settings
> >   >   >
> >   >   >   > - Security Settings
> >   >   >   >
> >   >   >   >   > - Local Policies
> >   >   >   >   >
> >   >   >   >   >   > - Security options
> >   >   >   >   >   >
> >   >   >   >   >   >   > Devices: prevent users from install printer : DISABLED
> >   >   > - Administrative Template (.. ADMX ..)
> >   >   >
> >   >   >   > - Printers
> >   >   >   >
> >   >   >   >   > - Add Printer Wizard-netwrk scan pg : Enabled
> >   >   >   >   >
> >   >   >   >   >   > Number of directory printers : 100
> >   >   >   >   > - Point and Print Restrictions : Enabled
> >   >   >   >   >
> >   >   >   >   >   > when installing .. new : do not show.. 
> >   >   >   >   >   >                  when updating .. exist : show only

thats all